# Handle the relationship of variables in Manipulate

Tags: manipulate

Dears. I want to plot a list of data in a time period as show in graph 1. It need to meet b>a, or error will occur as shown in graph 2. b=a+100 is tried in graph 3 but failed. Do you know how to solve this? Thanks!

[image: a need to be larger than b]

[image]

[image]

Comment: try `Manipulate[
 ListLinePlot[tableTemp[[;; a ;; b]]], {a, 1, 36000, 100}, {b, a + 99,
   36000, 100}]`?

Comment: Use `tableTemp[[;; a ;; Max[a, b]]]` to avoid the error ?

Comment: In general you can use `TrackingFunction` to manage changes.\

Comment: Thanks all. Both Max and TrackingFunction works!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use [`IntervalSlider`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/IntervalSlider.html) with the function syntax for the manipulate control.

First some data.

```
SeedRandom[15];
ts = RandomFunction[BinomialProcess[.01], {1, 36000}, 3];
```

Then

```
Manipulate[
 ListLinePlot[ts["ValueList"][[All, Span @@ loc]], DataRange -> loc],
 {{loc, {1000, 2000}},
  IntervalSlider[#, {1, 3600, 1},
    MinIntervalSize -> 100,
    Method -> "Push"] &,
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}
 ]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Could not be more helpful! Thanks